# Proxy setting for a single (or few) specific sites only

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, proxy, microsoft-edge

I'm looking for a way to set-up a **proxy setting** in my machine (with Edge and/or Chrome) to **open just a single specific site located behind the proxy, but not every other website I access**.

The system's (Windows 10) proxy settings work in a 'white-list' mode where, when set (the proxy), all traffic goes through the proxy, except for the white-listed ones.

I need the exact opposite behavior, a sort of 'black-list' behavior, so when set (the proxy), traffic will only go through the proxy for the few specified 'black-listed' site(s) and not the rest of my Internet traffic.

I know I can use these other solutions, but they are either messy or not efficient:

1. Set up another browser for proxy browsing, with specific proxy information. This renders this additional browser unusable without removing the proxy setting for all other sites and eats much more memory and resources (due to having 2 browsers running to open just an additional website).
2. Use of a browser extension for switching proxies. This is faster but doesn't allow the proxied websites to work along with non-proxied ones (especially those that are refreshed/updated dynamically).
3. Use of a scripted PAC configuration: I have found some solutions for Firefox, which has its own system-independent proxy settings, but haven't found how to achieve this with the system-wide proxy settings that MS Edge and Chrome use.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This should be achievable with a PAC file.  What is the issue that you have with it?